# How to view size of clustered index for a given table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Inherited the following audit table:

**Table UserActions**

```
AppID int
ActionTime datetime
Action varchar(25)
UserID int
Description text
```

Clustering key is on AppID, ActionTime, Action columns.
RowCount = appx 1 billion

How do I view the size of this particular clustered index in total and per row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the system stored procedure [`sp_spaceused`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the size of the Table which is going to be the size of your **clustered index** since the **clustered index** is the logical storage of the Table itself.

Example syntax: `EXEC sp_spaceused 'UserActions';`

Specifically you'd want to look at the `data` column of the result set since that will tell you the total size of the Table itself which is the **clustered index** size. (The `index_size` column is the total space consumed by all indexes, so could give different results depending on if you're using other indexes such as **nonclustered indexes** too.)

The **clustered index** size per row is going to vary on each row (dependent on if you have varying sized data types or nullable columns), but you can get an average per row by dividing that `data` column by  the `rows` column that the above procedure returns.

Comment: FYI, `sp_spaceused` is all lower-case. That matters with a case-sensitive instance collation.

Comment: @DanGuzman True, I think it's silly Microsoft mixes naming conventions across their own products. I prefer to use something more standard when referencing them. Unfortunately you're right that this is a case that could matter since you normally run `sp_spaceused` in a user database which could have a case sensitive collation itself. I updated my answer accordingly, thanks.